# Separar nombre y apellidos en SQL

Tags: sql

Cómo separar las palabras de la columna de la tabla según el espacio que hay entre ellas a traves de la consulta (Formato select) sin hacer ninguna modificación a la tabla.

En este caso específico busco separar el nombre, apellido paterno y apellido materno

ejemplo:

```
Juan Peterson Checo 
-Juan
-Peterson
-Checo
```

Comment: O sea, ¿tienes el nombre completo en una columna y quieres mostrar tres valores en un `SELECT`? Por favor, [edita tu pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/99096/edit) poniendo la etiqueta del manejador de base de datos que estás usando: MySQL, SQL Server, Oracle, Postgresql...

Answer (score 2):

Yo lo resolvería así.Teniendo algo como esto esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como no dices en que motor de bases de datos yo lo hice en MsSql Server

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En términos generales yo pienso que necesita un patrón para separar los componentes de la cadena. Yo use el espacio en blanco. Y lo que si es mas complicado es saber cuales son nombres y apellidos y cuantos son. Probablemente sea el mismo patrón en todos los registros así que solo debe acomodarlo

En la parte del código use las funciones PARSENAME y REPLACE. Que son quienes realmente hacen el trabajo, seria cuestión de verificar las equivalentes en el motor de bases de datos en caso de que sea diferente Microsoft Sql Server

```html
SELECT PARSENAME(REPLACE(Nombre,' ','.'),3) AS PrimerNombre,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Nombre,' ','.'),4) AS SegundoNombre,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Nombre,' ','.'),2) AS PrimerApellido,
PARSENAME(REPLACE(Nombre,' ','.'),1) AS SegundoApellido
FROM [Borreme].[dbo].[Personas]
```

Answer (score 2):

Aunque creo que esta tarea la tendrías que realizar en el lado backend sea en PHP, JS, Java, JS el que sea aquí va mi solución: una función que te resuelva el problema y la puedas reutilizar para más casos, en vez de tener tu select 'sucio':

> Función

```
CREATE FUNCTION split(val VARCHAR(255), del VARCHAR(255), pos INT)
RETURNS VARCHAR(255)
RETURN REPLACE(SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, del, pos),LENGTH(SUBSTRING_INDEX(val, del, pos-1)) + 1), del, '');
```

> Salida

```
SELECT split('Hola StackOverflow en español', ' ', 1); # 'Hola'
SELECT split('Hola StackOverflow en español', ' ', 2); # 'StackOverflow'
SELECT split('Hola StackOverflow en español', ' ', 3); # 'en'
SELECT split('Hola StackOverflow en español', ' ', 4); # 'español'
```

Answer (score 1):

Prueba con esta select para obtener el nombre y el apellido del campo "nombre" de la tabla "usuarios"

```
select left(nombre, CHARINDEX(' ', nombre)) as nombre_usuario,
substring(nombre, CHARINDEX(' ', nombre)+1, len(nombre)-(CHARINDEX(' ', 
nombre)-1)) as apellido_usuario
from usuarios
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, dejo mi colaboración en SQL Sever.

```
CREATE FUNCTION fn_ApellidosNombres
(
    @Nombre nvarchar(100)
)
RETURNS nvarchar(100)
AS
BEGIN
    declare @retorno nvarchar(100) = ''


    declare @cursor int, @conteoEspacios int = 0, @espacioEncontrado bit = 0, @ultimaPosicion int = 1, @conteoCaracteres int = 1
    declare @datos table (id int primary key identity(1,1), nombre nvarchar(30), na char(1))
    set @cursor = 1
    while(@cursor<= len(@Nombre)) begin
        if(select SUBSTRING(@Nombre, @cursor, 1)) =' ' begin
            if(@espacioEncontrado = 0) begin
                set @conteoEspacios +=1
                insert into @datos (nombre, na)
                select SUBSTRING(rtrim(ltrim(@Nombre)), @ultimaPosicion, @conteoCaracteres), case when (@conteoEspacios <= 2) then 'N' else 'A' end
                set @ultimaPosicion = @cursor + 1
                set @conteoCaracteres = 0
                
            end
            set @espacioEncontrado = 1;
            
        end
        else begin
             set @espacioEncontrado = 0;
        end
        set @cursor += 1
        set @conteoCaracteres += 1
        if(@cursor = len(@Nombre)) begin
            insert into @datos (nombre, na)
            select SUBSTRING(ltrim(rtrim(@Nombre)), @ultimaPosicion, @conteoCaracteres), 'A'
        end
    end

    set @retorno = ( SELECT concat( (select CONCAT(replace(nombre,' ',''), ' ') from @datos where na = 'A' for xml path('')), (select CONCAT(replace(nombre,' ',''), ' ') from @datos where na = 'N' for xml path('')) ))
    return @retorno
END
```

Comment: Tu respuesta es solo codigo. Por favor mira [answer]. Se pide que expliques que hace este código (mas alla que a ti vos te parezca obvio, puede que otro usuario no lo vea tan simple). De paso, esto no es un foro (Es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas), no es un hilo cerrado (hay una pregunta, y hay tantas respuestas como sean validas) y ya que la pregunta no aclara para que base de datos, tu respuesta deberia aclarar en que base de datos funciona esto.